# How to include the spark-examples.jar as a dependency within a maven/sbt project?

Tags: apache-spark

The `spark-examples.jar` is apparently not published to maven. That is a complication when attempting to build atop those classes in an `maven` /`sbt` project.

Further compounding this problem is that it seems that `mvn install` were set up to `skip` when going through the process of downloading spark, building from source, and installing locally:

```
mvn -pl examples install

[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ spark-examples_2.11 ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact installation
```

It seems I will have to spelunk into the spark examples `pom.xml` to see how to re-enable installation?  Overall this is a non trivial process: any pointers to a quicker path appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a band-aid would be as hinted in the OP: remove the `skip` from the `install` plugin invocation:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <!--  <skip>true</skip>  -->
    </configuration>
```

A more straightforward approach to adding the `spark-examples` dependency would still be appreciated (and likely awarded).